# how to sort out values in a certain time period in R?

Tags: if-statement

I´ve got a time series of temperature data with some wrong values, I want to sort out. The problem is, I want to sort out only the points in a certain period of time.
If I sort out the wrong points by their temperature value, ALL of the points of this temperature value are sorted out (through the wohle measuring period)
This is a very easy version of my code (in reality, there are many more values)

`laketemperature <- c(15, 14, 14, 12, 11, 9, 9, 8, 6, 4, 15, 14, 3) #only want to sort out the last 14 and 15`

`out <- c(15, 14)`

`laketemperature_clean <- laketemperature [- out] # the 15 and 14s at the beginning are sorted out, too :(`

I want to have the whole laketemperature-series in the end, only without the second 15.
I already tried with ifelse, but it didn´t work out.

Comment: Which language is this? R it can't be due to the trailing comma in the first code line.

Comment: it IS R. The comma was just set wrong, sorry!

Comment: What you write is not in accordance with the facts - `laketemperature [- c(15, 14)]` does not sort _out_ _the 15 and 14s_, but rather the 14th and 15th array element (if there were such), nothing else,